# Open source content for data analysis?

Tags: data-mining

Where can I find data in general for analysis purposes ? I am currently learning data mining. It would be nice if I can get live data or facts.I am ok if the content is in xml,csv,text,etc(in some common format).I remember seeing a site which contained data in graph format, similar to graph databases. But couldn't remember the site. Can somebody give me some links for the same? I can use database like adventure_works but I am need of current data like earth quake history ,population details,etc.

Comment: I want to know, why was this closed as off topic??? I needed sources and I ve got them. Can somebody explain why this was closed???

Comment: because it is not a *programming* question. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply.Is there any other forum for asking these kind of questions? If you know any, please let me know.

Comment: Google will find a lot of data sets for you. Universities have been collecting data sets for years.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try https://nycopendata.socrata.com/ - NYC's open and public data sets.

On Amazon AWS you can also "mount" dataset volumes as well - http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/

Answer (score 1):

Some more sites...

1. And http://dbpedia.org contains structured data from wikipedia ,
2. http://opentick.com/ contains historical financial data
3. http://www.statsci.org/datasets.html
4. http://data.worldbank.org/country
5. http://bjs.ojp.usdoj.gov/rawdata.cfm

Answer (score 0):

I found the site, its http://www.freebase.com/. Would really appreciate, if people can pour in more data sources.

Answer (score 0):

Few more:

- Global Terrorism Database - http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/
- Newsgroups - http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/
- Google public data sets - http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory
- http://webscope.sandbox.yahoo.com/catalog.php?datatype=c
- http://learningtorankchallenge.yahoo.com/datasets.php